# asp.net Add image to first item in table

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Im wroking on a website built in .net and im struggling trying to add an image to the first row in a table.

I have the following code that outputs a table with say 20 rows.

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>
                <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>.
                <%#Eval("Alias")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("Bench")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>.
                <%#Eval("Alias")%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("Bench")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
```

Is there a way to count the first row and if so add an image to that? 
I hope this makes sense, thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though probably not the most ideal way, you should be able to accomplish this with a conditional statement like so:

```
<%# (Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex")) == 0) ? "<img src='something.gif'>" : "" %>.
```

If the Index is 0, then it's the first item, and you can write out your image. You may have to swap out ItemIndex with DataItemIndex depending on what you're using.